# Syntax Error during cypher query neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
 neo4j-sh start person=node(*) match person-[:HAS_STORED]->
 contact-[:HAS_NUMBER]-> (p{tn:"455"}) return contact;
```

==> SyntaxException: Properties on pattern elements are not allowed in MATCH.

==>

==> Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to `cypher@neo4j.org`.

==> Thank you, the Neo4j Team.

==>

==> `"start person=node(*) match person-[:HAS_STORED]->
      contact-[:HAS_NUMBER]->(phone{tn:"455"}) return contact"`

==>                                                                                                  ^

what this error means?

what is the other way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do:

```
start person=node(*) 
match person-[:HAS_STORED]->contact-[:HAS_NUMBER]->(p)
where p.tn="455" 
return contact;
```

If you're looking for speed, do an index lookup in `START`:

```
start p=node:node_auto_index(tn="455")
match person-[:HAS_STORED]->contact-[:HAS_NUMBER]->p
return contact;
```

Comment: sir yeah i can do it this way also but this query i think will be slow compare to earlier one

Comment: The other one isn't a valid query, so I don't think there's much of a contest for speed. I'll post an update that might help.

Comment: sir actually person and contact has 1 to n relationship so the query has to be like this

Comment: start person=node:PersonIndex(id="12") 
match person-[:HAS_STORED]->contact-[:HAS_NUMBER]->p
where p.tn="455"
return contact;

how can i optimise this....?

Comment: it doesn't matter what the direction is. the pattern will be able to start from either end.

Comment: what sort of statistics do you have in your database? How many contacts per person and numbers per contact?

Comment: contacts per person is around 500 and numbers may be 4

Comment: that shouldn't be too bad--is it a slow query?